# JavaScript: How to Get the Values from a Multi-Dimensional Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get the values from a multi-dimensional array. This is what I have so far.
I need the value of 99 and the image when I select the first option in the array, e.g. "Billy Joel".

```
var concertArray = [
    ["Billy Joel", "99", "equal.png"],
    ["Bryan Adams", "89", "higher.png"],
    ["Brian Adams", "25", "lower.png"]
];

function populate(){
    for(i = 0; i < concertArray.length; i++){
        var select = document.getElementById("test");
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(concertArray[i][0], concertArray[i][1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can try to transform the multi-dimensional array to an array of objects like this:

```
var concertArray = [
    {name: "Billy Joel", value: 99, image: "equal.png"},
    {name: "Bryan Adams", value: 89, image: "higher.png"},
    {name: "Brian Adams", value: 25, image: "lower.png"}
];
```

Then you can access the items in the array like regular objects:

```
var concertName = concertArray[0].name;
var concertPrice = parseFloat(concertArray[0].value);
var concertImage = concertArray[0].image;
```

Comment: How to iterate this kind of an array?

Answer (score 6):

```js
let concertArray = [
    ["Billy Joel", "99", "equal.png"],
    ["Bryan Adams", "89", "higher.png"],
    ["Brian Adams", "25", "lower.png"]
];

let i = 0;

console.log(concertArray[i][1]) // 99
console.log(concertArray[i][2]) // equal.png
```

Comment: Thanks so much....

Now, what would I have to do to complete the concertImage in this structure:

concertName = concertList.options[concertIndex].text;
concertPrice = parseFloat(concertList.options[concertIndex].value);
concertImage = ???

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the `Option` constructor only takes two arguments, the text and the `value`. If you want to pass more data, I suggest you use the HTML5 data API:

```
var opt = new Option(concertArray[i][0], concertArray[i][1]);
opt.setAttribute('data-image', concertArray[i][2]);
select.options[select.options.length] = opt;
```

Then you can grab it using `getAttribute('data-image')`

Answer (score 0):

You can access values by using 2 for loops as below.

```
var concertArray = [
    ["Billy Joel", "99", "equal.png"],
    ["Bryan Adams", "89", "higher.png"],
    ["Brian Adams", "25", "lower.png"]
    ];

function populate(){
    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++)
        {
             console.log(arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is awfully bad for large arrays.